# JavaFX: MediaPlayer cannot play the movie

Tags: java, video, media-player, javafx-2, javafx

I'm trying my first MediaPlayer javafx application. I followed a lot of how-to but i'm still not able to run a video on a new application.

What's wrong with this:

```
Media m = new Media ("file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/User/Desktop/samples/kick.mp4");
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
MediaView mv = new MediaView(mp);

Group root = new Group();
root.getChildren().add(mv);
stage.setScene(new Scene(root,400,400));
stage.setTitle("Media Player");
stage.show();
mp.play();
```

The app builds correctly, no "file not found exception" is fired, but the player is stuck in the UNKNOWN status and the raised window is with a white, fixed background. Neither any kind of audio is provided.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Is the onReady event ever fired? That might provide some more clues as to the nature of the problem.

Comment: never, but i resolved with the codec setup. Thanks for your time in any case! :)

Comment: No problem! That was where I was going to head next. Glad you got it fixed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!
I'm running on Windows XP, therefore i'm missing some codec.

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/system_requirements_2-2/jfxpub-system_requirements_2-2.htm):

```
For Windows XP and Windows Vista, JavaFX Media 2.2 requires that one of the following
external modules be installed to play AAC audio and H.264/AVC video:

MainConcept H.264/AVC Pro Decoder Pack
DivX Plus Codec Pack
MainConcept Showcase (includes demo version codecs)
```

Installing DivX codecs did the trick!